# Create OR filter with django_filters

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset, django-filter

I want to create an OR filter in my django_filters.
All filters with perfect, except my productname.

I have a searchbox that needs to search for a productname in the column name_nl, name_en and name_fr.

How can I create an or filter with Django_filter?

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
status = django_filters.CharFilter(name='productvariant__status_id', lookup_type='exact')
productname = django_filters.CharFilter(name='name_nl', lookup_type='icontains')

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = {
        'productname': ['icontains'],
        'status': ['exact']
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Since 1.x version, [MethodFilter was removed](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/migration.html#methodfilter-and-filter-action-replaced-by-filter-method-382). Now it looks like:

```
import django_filters
from django.db.models import Q

from app.models import User

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    q = filters.CharFilter(method='filter_q')

    def filter_q(self, qs, name, value):
        return qs.filter(
            Q(last_name__icontains=value) | Q(first_name__icontains=value) | Q(email__icontains=value)
        )
```

and for the view

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView

from .filters import UserFilter

class AgentListView(ClassRequiredMixin, FilterView):

    filterset_class = UserFilter
```

Note that if you're using DRF then `filterset_class` in 2.x is named `filter_class` in 1.x

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class AgentListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_class = UserFilter
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this.

```
import django_filters
from django.db.models import Q

from app.models import User

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    q = django_filters.MethodFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []

    def filter_q(self, queryset, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(last_name__icontains=value) | Q(first_name__icontains=value) | Q(email__icontains=value)
        )
```

Then make a generic view.

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView

from .filters import UserFilter

class AgentListView(ClassRequiredMixin, FilterView):

    filterset_class = UserFilter
```

For your template see http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#the-template

Comment: This has now been deprecated: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/migration.html#methodfilter-and-filter-action-replaced-by-filter-method-382  You should instead do it with the `method` parameter it seems

Answer (score -4):

You can use [Q() objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

From the documentation:

```
Poll.objects.get(
    Q(question__startswith='Who'),
    Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2)) | Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6))
)
```

Gives something like:

```
SELECT * from polls WHERE question LIKE 'Who%'
    AND (pub_date = '2005-05-02' OR pub_date = '2005-05-06')
```

Comment: Actually the questioner is talking about this: http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: In that case he may want to read: https://github.com/alex/django-filter/issues/137

Comment: Actually I want a filter like this (width django_filter):

http://example.com/api/products?name_nl=search_string,name_fr=search_string,name_en=search_string

I already use the Q() objects somewhere else in my application. But here I need to use the django_filter...